# Error while converting pipelined RDD to Dataframe in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to convert the below pipelined RDD into dataframe.

Pipelined RDD -> user_rdd

```
['new_user1',
 'new_user2',
 'Onlyknows',
 'Icetea',
 '_coldcoffee_']
```

I tried to convert using the below code

```
schema = StructType([StructField('Username', StringType(), True)])
user_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(user_rdd,schema)
mention_df.show(20)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ValueError: Unexpected tuple 'new_user1' with StructType
```

I tried using toDF() also:

```
user_df=user_rdd.toDF()
```

This time the error encountered is:

```
TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: <type 'str'>
```

Let me know if there is a way to convert this to dataframe using pyspark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rdd you have is a list of strings, which is essentially 1d data; A data frame requires 2d data; Convert each element in the rdd to a tuple should resolve the issue:

```
user_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(user_rdd.map(lambda x: (x,)), schema)
#                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
user_df.show()
+------------+
|    Username|
+------------+
|   new_user1|
|   new_user2|
|   Onlyknows|
|      Icetea|
|_coldcoffee_|
+------------+
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. It worked !!!

Comment: @shankarBalu Glad it helps.